# Query with ommited period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, where one of the columns contains city name.

Most cities are OK, but some may have abbreviations with or without a period

> Ft. Worth
>
> Ft Worth

If I have a value to Without a period `Ft Worth` how can I query the table to find all matching cities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression to make the period optional:

```
WHERE city RLIKE 'Ft[.]? Worth'
```

If you want to ignore all periods in the table when comparing with a search string:

```
WHERE REPLACE(city, '.', '') = 'Ft Worth'
```

Comment: It's actually a dynamic script that goes through a list of cities. I user Ft Worth as an example. The value will always be without periods. Is there a way to ignore periods in the table, if they are present?

Answer (score 1):

I might be inclined to use `replace()`:

```
select replace(city, '.', '') = 'Ft Worth'
```

One nice aspect of this approach is that you can use `in`:

```
select replace(city, '.', '') in ('Ft Worth', 'Gun Barrel City', 'Kermit')
```

However, I would be suspicious and think that there might be other problems.  For instance, you might have "Fort Worth".

In any case, you should clean the data:

```
update t
    set city = 'Ft Worth'
    where city = 'Ft. Worth';
```

or

```
update t
    set city = replace(city, '.', '')
    where city like '%. %';
```

Comment: Oh, can I do something like: SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE replace(city, '.', '') = 'Ft Worth' ? I think this is what I was looking for.